# interactivePopGesture causes delay after popping some viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

interactivePopGesture works fine when i launch my application. But after some pops there is some lag in transition between my viewControllers while using interactivePopGesture.
  I have a base View controller and 5 other view controllers which extend my base controller.
When i launch my app for the first time, the interactivePopGetures works good for first few attempts. But after some time there is some lag in transition between my view Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apps memory usage to see if you aren't loading something multiple times into the memory.